# TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions

Tags: error-messages, navigationmixin.navigate, lightningnavigation

I wrote such functionality to see pdf ContentDocument preview of needeed file:

```javascript
viewPdf() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            pageName: 'filePreview'
        },
        state : {
            recordIds: contentDocumentId.data,
            selectedRecordId: contentDocumentId.data
        }
    });
}
```

I watched how my code works in Debug mode and see that ContentDocumentId.data receives the needed Id. But when I look at NavigationMixin.Navigate, I see such 'arguments' and 'caller':

**Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.invokeGetter**

Update:
I wrote try-catch block.
[image: As you can see, there is ContentDocumentId]

[image: And here we ca see that ContentDocumentId is undefined]

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Just as a clarification - the browser doesn't navigate to the preview page and the PDF is not rendered, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I click the button and nothing happens. In debug mode I see error as a value of 'arguments' and 'caller'.

Comment: Could you add a console.log at the end of viewPdf or make sure in another way that the Exception is indeed thrown while executing this[NavigationMixin.Navigate] ?

Comment: I just made it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `this.` in front of `contentDocumentId` - `contentDocumentId` is not local :-)

Comment: Oh, thank you :) It's embarrassing a little. Mistake was so silly and I didn't notice it. Now everything is great.

Comment: Don't worry, it took me time too! In life, simple problems can be the hardest nuts to crack. The next thing we do might already be something really clever.